# SQL Server Tree Hierarchy and Nested Sets with Duplicate Record ids

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, tree, nested-sets

Given that I have this resultset structure (superfluous fields have been stripped)

```
Id | ParentId | Name | Depth
----------------------------
```

is it possible to have the records returned in tree order i.e. `Parent` then `Children`, if a `Child` is a `Parent`, then their `Children`, if not then `Sibling`, etc? For example,

```
Id | ParentId | Name | Depth
----------------------------
1    NULL       Major    1
2    1          Minor    2
3    1          Minor    2
4    3          Build    3
5    3          Build    3
6    1          Minor    2

/* etc, etc */
```

The only way that I can think of doing this would be to follow this article -

[Improve hierarchy performance using nested sets](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/nestedsets.aspx)

and include `[LeftExtent]` and `[RightExtent]` fields against each record. Now the SQL in the article works fine when `Ids` are unique, but in this particular tree structure, a record with the same `Id` can appear in different places within the tree (the `ParentId` field is different, obviously). I think the problem is in this SQL from the article -

```
  INSERT INTO @tmpStack
    (
      EmployeeID, 
      LeftExtent
    )
  SELECT TOP 1 EmployeeID, @counter 
  FROM Employee 
  WHERE ISNULL(ParentID, 0) = ISNULL(@parentid,0) 
  /* If the Id has already been added then record is not given [LeftExtent] or [RightExtent] values. */
  AND EmployeeID NOT IN (SELECT EmployeeID FROM @tmpStack)
```

How can this be altered to allow records with duplicate `Ids` to be given [LeftExtent] and [RightExtent] values, or I am completely missing an easier way to return the resultset in the order that I require?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one that does the trick for me:

@ParentID is just a starting point in the hierarchy, but you can pass in 0 (but I think you're using null as the base ID, so you'll get the idea)

The key to ordered sorting is with the sort key that's built up.

```
WITH RoleHierarchy (RoleID, [Role], [Description], ParentID, Editable, HierarchyLevel, SortKey) AS
(
   -- Base
   SELECT
        RoleID,
        [Role],
        [Description],
        ParentID,
        Editable,
        0 as HierarchyLevel,
        CAST(RoleID AS VARBINARY(300))
   FROM
        dbo.Roles       
   WHERE
        RoleID = @ParentID

   UNION ALL

   -- Recursive
   SELECT
        e.RoleID,
        e.[Role],
        e.[Description],
        e.ParentID,
        e.Editable,
        th.HierarchyLevel + 1 AS HierarchyLevel,
        CAST (th.SortKey + CAST (e.[Role] AS VARBINARY(100)) + CAST (e.[RoleID] AS VARBINARY(100)) AS VARBINARY(300))
   FROM
        Roles e
        INNER JOIN RoleHierarchy th ON e.ParentID = th.RoleID
    WHERE
        e.RoleID != 0
)

SELECT
    RoleID,
    ParentID,
    [Role],
    [Description],
    Editable,
    HierarchyLevel
FROM
    RoleHierarchy
WHERE
    RoleID != @ParentID
ORDER BY
    SortKey
```

Comment: Well, let me know if you notice anything strange as I've been using this for a while!

Comment: your solution works great, i use seq (sequence) column instead of primary key and it works. I also found more detailed sortkey explanation here http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Development/recursivequeriesinsqlserver2005/1760/

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at recursive common table expressions in SQL Server 2005:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20210927200924/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071906-1.shtml
- http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Development/recursivequeriesinsqlserver2005/1760/

In your case, this would be something like:

```
WITH EmployeeCTE AS
(
   -- get the anchor
   SELECT ID, ParentID, Name, 0 as 'Depth'
   FROM Employee WHERE ParentID IS NULL

   -- recursively union lower levels
   UNION ALL
   SELECT e.ID, e.ParentID, e.Name, e.Depth+1
   FROM Employee e
   INNER JOIN EmployeeCTE ON e.ParentID = EmployeeCTE.ID
)
SELECT * FROM EmployeeCTE
```

This should give you a nice query result set with the data you're looking for. Or am I missing something?

Marc

Comment: I have a CTE currently to recursively join records to build the resultset. This works fine, but the problem is that the order of records in the resultset is not in the order I would like as specified in the question. I'll amend the question to state resultset structure as opposed to table structure

Answer (score 0):

If you used [materialized path](http://www.dbazine.com/oracle/or-articles/tropashko4) or [HIERARCHYID](http://pratchev.blogspot.com/2008/05/hierarchies-in-sql-server-2008.html), you life would be much easier...

Comment: HIERARCHYID looks interesting, but alas, the solution is to work with SQL Server 2005

Comment: Materialized path does work on 2005, and it can make your life much eaiser