# Displaying Same Result-Set Hierarchical Data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data

I have 3 tables, Let's say `TierOne`, `TierTwo`, `TierThree`

`TierTwo` has a foreign key to `TierOne` and `TierTwo` has a foreign key to `TierThree`

So I could have data like the following:

TierOne

```
ID        title 
1         Tier1 Item1        
2         Tier1 Item2        
3         Tier1 Item3
```

TierTwo

```
ID        ParentID        title 
1         1               Tier2 Item1       
2         1               Tier2 Item2        
3         2               Tier2 Item3 
4         2               Tier2 Item4
5         3               Tier2 Item5
```

TierThree

```
ID        ParentID        title 
1         1               Tier3 Item1       
2         1               Tier3 Item2        
3         2               Tier3 Item3 
4         2               Tier3 Item4
5         3               Tier3 Item5
6         4               Tier3 Item6
7         5               Tier3 Item7
```

Now, the problem: Over the three tables I have 15 rows, I need to display each tier and it's children one by one. Desired output: *Note I have tabbed the change in tiers for easier viewing.

```
title 
Tier1 Item1       
  Tier2 Item1
    Tier3 Item1   
    Tier3 Item2 
  Tier2 Item2
    Tier3 Item3
    Tier3 Item4
Tier1 Item2
  Tier2 Item3
    Tier3 Item5
  Tier2 Item4
    Tier3 Item6
Tier1 Item3
  Tier2 Item5
    Tier3 Item7
```

I have tried using CTE with tier1 and tier2 but the result set was huge.

Comment: Please have a look at this answer 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124677/sql-server-tree-hierarchy-and-nested-sets-with-duplicate-record-ids/1124724#1124724

Comment: If that is the case, can't you do a CTE between First and Second tier, and then from this result you do another CTE with the Third tier?

Comment: @doganak This example will not order the tiers in the way that I need